# using themename_the_custom_logo() in template-tags?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options, template-tags

I am trying to learn how to create a theme for wordpress so i looked at the default theme 'twenty sixteen'. I was crawling around it and searching everything that i find strange then i saw this code in " wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\inc\template-tags.php "file

```
function twentysixteen_the_custom_logo() {
if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
    the_custom_logo();
}
}
```

and then we have this on header.php file

```
<?php twentysixteen_the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

so i'm a bit confused here i tried to look it up on google but there was nothing helpful

first of all why he did not use the_custom_logo() method itself in the header file 
and second what is the use of the_custom_logo() method anyway ? what can we add to this method ?

references I searched my problem [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_custom_logo/) and a bunch of other sites

btw, I'm newbie at both html and wordpress , I know how to code with php though

and if u know a good source for creating a theme for wp I will appreciate your sharing <3

(sorry for bad English )

Answer (score 0):

> first of all why he did not use the_custom_logo() method itself in the header file

This function checks that the `the_custom_logo` function exists for backwards compatibility, so that the function works on WordPress versions older than 4.5.

The reason this is done in inside `twentysixteen_the_custom_logo()` is so the theme can just use a single function in the template, without adding that `if` statement:

```
<?php twentysixteen_the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

vs

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
    the_custom_logo();
}
?>
```

> and second what is the use of the_custom_logo() method anyway ? what can we add to this method ?

Themes can support a [Custom Logo](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/) feature. This function outputs the selected logo.

> and if u know a good source for creating a theme for wp I will appreciate your sharing <3

You should start with the theme handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/ But I would advise learning some basic HTML, CSS and PHP first.